# Nextflow download dataset and create a Channel.fromFilePairs

Tags: groovy, nextflow

I have a process that downloads the dataset (a directory) and I want to return a channel fromFilePairs from that process. How do I achieve it? Do I return somehow the output directory name, or can I output a channel directly?

Comment: Could you describe a bit more about the process that downloads the dataset directory? Instead of downloading the directory itself, could you instead download each of the files using a manifest for example? Or is the directory like a tarball that you then need to untar/unzip?